# Getting Marionette layouts to render like backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm attempting to get a marionette layout to render like a backbone view. Ie, I've declared a tagName and an id and I want it to generate a dom element based of that. For such a simplistic element, it seems redundant to have to make a template stub just for that.

HTML:

```
<body><div id="page"></div></body>
```

Test code:

```
var HeaderBar = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: "headerBar"

});

/*========== APP Tests ============*/
App = Marionette.Application.extend({});

var MyApp = new App();
MyApp.addRegions({
    pageRegion: "#page"
});



var header = new HeaderBar();
MyApp.pageRegion.show(header);
```

However, calling show from the app throws the TemplateNotFoundError.

I'm looking for a way to have Marionette render this without a template and without having to commandeer the render function in the library.

Comment: The reason it needs a template is so you can render regions. If you aren't using regions in your layout you should be using an ItemView. If you are, all you need to do is render the region containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
var HeaderBar = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: _.template("<div></div>"),
    id: "headerBar"

});
```

See https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.renderer.md#using-pre-compiled-templates

Comment: It ends up creating an extra div so you have to do _.template("") but that does work.

Answer (score 0):

`Layout`s require a template because they need to render regions inside of them.  If you aren't using any regions with your layout, you don't need to use a `Layout`; use an `ItemView` instead:

```
var HeaderBar = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: "headerBar"
});
```

Then use it as normal with your region.

If you do, however, need regions inside `HeaderBar`, then yes, you need a template with a `Layout`.